# Upload text file to web service

Tags: c#, .net, asmx, webclient, webclient.uploaddata

I have following method which accepts a text file and I am trying to upload this text file on the web service. I use a user name and a password. But I get an exception:
"The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.". If I supply the user name and password again I get the same exception. What should I do to overcome this issue?

```
public static void UploadTextFileToWebService(string txtFile)
{
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    string webAddress = null;
    try
    {
        webAddress = @"https://www.myweb.org/mywebwebservices/dataupload.asmx";
        webClient.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

        WebRequest serverRequest = WebRequest.Create(webAddress);
        WebResponse serverResponse;
        serverResponse = serverRequest.GetResponse();
        serverResponse.Close();              
        webClient.UploadFile(webAddress + txtFile, "PUT", txtFile);
        webClient.Dispose();
        webClient = null;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the web service? Also, don't use `ex.Message` as a diagnostic output. Use `ex.ToString()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your webservice seems to be an asmx webservice so i doubt you can do the upload the way you are trying to.

You need to use the correct SoapMessage format to send whatever requests you are sending.

Since you are using C#/.Net your easiest path would be to add a service reference which would create a proxy to enable you send your request via an object model.

Comment: Can you please share few links for the same. Thanks

Comment: @user1399377 You could try looking at this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628649.aspx

Comment: A service reference to an ASMX service won't give the service the capability to upload files.

Comment: @JohnSaunders the assumption is that he has read the file into a string (since he says text file) and will pass that as a parameter to the WebMethod of the Webserivce :)

Comment: I prefer not to assume, which is why I asked to see the service.

Comment: @JohnSaunders if you go through his page, you'll notice he has been on this for a while. Someone else suggested he go the webclient route.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you've got the approach right here - since you've already read the file as a string, you should just send the content of the string to a webmethod that accepts the contents of the text file directly.

So in your service you should have (something like):

```
[WebMethod()]
public void AcceptFile(string content)
{
    ...
}
```

You then call that method and pass the txtFile variable as the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

parm 1 is wrong in this line:

```
webClient.UploadFile(webAddress + txtFile, "PUT", txtFile);
```

and probably should be

```
webClient.UploadFile(webAddress + @"/" + txtFile, "PUT", txtFile);
```